# javaScript to determine which p element is being hovered over to invoke event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onmouseover

I’m building a site for a retailer. I’m working on their store locations page, which has 4 different street locations. Each street address is wrapped in its own paragraph tag. All four paragraphs are inside a div container which has an ID named “box_1”.

I’ve written an event handler that changes the background color of the first paragraph element. However, I don’t want to write the same redundant code for the other 3 paragraphs, if I don’t have to.

I want JS to first determine which paragraph is being hovered over and take its position in the array and load it into the brackets in the event handler. 
Example: hover mouse over paragraph 2 and load “1” into element[1].onmouseover = function() {// my code};

Below is the code I have so far:

```
<div id="box_1">
<p>18901 Kansas Avenue, Jimmytown, NE </p>
<p>5015 Cornman Lane, Crybaby, MN </p>
<p>847 Halfstack Avenue, Crumble, GA </p>
 </div>

// javaScript:
var divPoint = document.getElementById("box_1"); // ID for the div
var mousePoint = divPoint.getElementsByTagName("p"); // p elements inside div

// mouseover event handler
mousePoint[0].onmouseover = function() {
mousePoint[0].style.backgroundColor = "#a80";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, attach the event to the `div`. In `onmouseover` function, you can have a variable name `event`. Then, call `event.target` to get the element triggering the event.

You may want to implement `onmouseout` also to clear the background. Here is the code.

```
var divPoint = document.getElementById("box_1");

divPoint.onmouseover = function(event) {
    var element = event.target;

    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p') {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#a80";
    }
};

divPoint.onmouseout = function(event) {
    var element = event.target;

    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p') {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    }
};
```

You can test it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ersk7ko9/).

For more information about `event.target`, please take a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css, no need for the javascript. If you do have to use js for whatever reason, atatch the event to the div and use the event target to select the correct p element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        #box_1 > p:hover {
            background-color: #a80;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box_1">
    <p>18901 Kansas Avenue, Jimmytown, NE </p>
    <p>5015 Cornman Lane, Crybaby, MN </p>
    <p>847 Halfstack Avenue, Crumble, GA </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```